# Oracle DB Connectivity in ADO.net (Couldn't able to Add Ref to OracleClient)

Tags: asp.net, oracle, visual-studio-2010

Following is the code I was trying to compile

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OracleClient;

Datatable EmpTable = new Datatable();
string oradb = ""

OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);
conn.Open();

string sql = "Select * from emp";
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql,conn);

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

EmpTable.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
```

But i am not able to add the reference to OracleClient Library since it doesn't appear in Add reference Window in Visual Studio 2010 even after installing Oracle 11g.

Kindly Help.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to use Nuget Package manager to download a Oracle Library client package to be added as a reference:

[**Oracle Data Provider for .NET (ODP.NET) Managed Driver**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/odp.net.managed/)